# Agrupar dados por Mes/Ano

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

BASE_GERAL = pd.read_csv('base_prestadores.csv')
```

---

```
indice | data_utilização| preço  | quantidade_itens
1      | 2014-05-01     | 20.00  |    5
2      | 2014-05-08     | 30.00  |    6
3      | 2014-04-10     | 50.00  |    8
4      | 2014-04-15     | 20.00  |    10
```

Importei a tabela acima e preciso agrupar os dados por mês/ano, considerando a soma da quantidade de itens como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Em qual formato você espera que os dados saiam?, tudo que for o mesmo mês vai somar o preço e a quantidade de itens?

Comment: Quero montar um gráfico de barras, considerando somente a soma das quantidades dos itens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz esse código. Espero que ajude.

```
import pandas as pd

#garanto que as colunas então com o type certo
df['data_utilizacao'] = df['data_utilizacao'].astype('datetime64')
df['quantidade_itens'] = df['quantidade_itens'].astype('int')

#crio uma coluna mes_ano
df['mes_ano'] = df['data_utilizacao'].map(lambda x: 100*x.year + x.month)

#pego só as colunas que interessam
df = df.ix[:, ['mes_ano', 'quantidade_itens']]

#junto pelo mes_ano igual somando a quantidade_itens
df = df.groupby(['mes_ano']).sum().reset_index()

>>> print(df)
   mes_ano  quantidade_itens
0   201404                18
1   201405                11
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo!